# How to get RadioNodeList with a single item in the group?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

When I have this form

```
<form id="frm">
  <input type="radio" name="test" value="a">
</form>
```

calling `frm.test.value = "b"` gets the input Node and changes the attribute value. On the other hand in this form

```
<form id="frm">
  <input type="radio" name="test" value="a">
  <input type="radio" name="test" value="b">
</form>
```

calling `frm.test.value = "b"` gets RadioNodeList object and checks the radiobutton with value "b" (if any).

Is it possible to obtain RadioNodeList object with length less than 2 to safely call `myobj.value = "b"` to check radiobutton (if any with such value) and not change its value attribute?

**I don't look for any workaround like checking the type or some silly recipes like**

```
const checkRadioValue = (frm, name, value) => frm &&
  frm.querySelectorAll(`[name=${name}]`).forEach(item =>
    item.checked = item.value==value
  )
```

I want to safely obtain RadioNodeList (or equivalent live collection) from the DOM without testing how many radiobuttons are in the group.

Comment: `RadioNodeLists` consists of two or more `<input name="${rnlName}" type="radio">`. There are no special features for a single radio button that doesn't share an identical `[name]` value with another radio button which is actually useless. Is there a reason why a form control that can be checked but not unchecked useful to your situation?

Answer (score 1):

A `RadioNodeList` does not get returned if there is only one radio button in the "group". It is an interface that encompasses a `NodeList` of `<inputs>` of type `radio`.

**Note:** You will not be able to manually encapsulate a single `<input type="radio">` inside a `RadioNodeList`, because it is not instantiable. You will need to add a check, as describe below, to safely set the value of a single radio.

In order to "safely" check a radio button value, you need to check if it is a `RadioNodeList` or an `<input type="checkbox">` element. If it is a `RadioNodeList` simply attempt to set the value. But if it is a single element, you will need to compare the input value and then set `checked` to `true`.

```js
const isRadio = (input) =>
  input && input.tagName === 'INPUT' && input.type === 'radio';

const setRadioValue = (radio, value) => {
  if (radio instanceof RadioNodeList) {
    radio.value = value; // Attempt to find a valid value
  } else if (isRadio(radio) && radio.value === value) {
    radio.checked = true;
  }
};

// Will not change value
setRadioValue(document.forms['frm-fail-1'].elements.test, 'c');
setRadioValue(document.forms['frm-fail-2'].elements.test, 'b');

// Will change value
setRadioValue(document.forms['frm-pass-1'].elements.test, 'b');
setRadioValue(document.forms['frm-pass-2'].elements.test, 'a');
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: border-box; }
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); }
body > div { display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; justify-content: center; gap: 0.5em; }
form { display: flex; border: thin dashed red; padding: 0.25em; gap: 0.25em; }
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Fail</h2>
  <form id="frm-fail-1">
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="a">
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="b">
  </form>
  <form id="frm-fail-2">
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="a">
  </form>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>Pass</h2>
  <form id="frm-pass-1">
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="a">
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="b">
  </form>
  <form id="frm-pass-2">
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="a">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I explicitly asked how to get RadioNodeList object with length less than 2, not to do workarounds like checking the type.

Comment: @JanTuroň a `RadioNodeList` does not get returned if there is only one radio button in the "group". It is an interface that encompasses a `NodeList` of `<inputs>` of type `radio`. I updated my response and included this first.

Comment: I am aware of that, and [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-dom-interfaces.html#radionodelist) is the autoritative algorithm. However it is not clear if RadioNodeList can be obtained some other way than calling namedItem (indirectly from form.elements).

Comment: @JanTuroň your linked documentation states: _"If there are multiple matching items, then a `RadioNodeList` object containing all those elements is returned."_ This means that you will not receive a collection if there is only one matching item.

Comment: Exactly. What is missing there is "this is the only way to obtain RadioNodeList". Or is it not?

Comment: @JanTuroň yes, you will need TWO or more radio buttons with the same name to retrieve a `RadioNodeList`.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of `namedItem(name)` is described [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-dom-interfaces.html#radionodelist) as

> 1. If name is the empty string, return **null** and stop the algorithm.
> 2. If, at the time the method is called, there is exactly one node in the collection that has either an id attribute or a name attribute equal to name, then return that **node** and stop the algorithm.
> 3. Otherwise, if there are no nodes in the collection that have either an id attribute or a name attribute equal to name, then return **null** and stop the algorithm.
> 4. Otherwise, create a new RadioNodeList object representing a live view of the HTMLFormControlsCollection object, further filtered so that the only nodes in the RadioNodeList object are those that have either an id attribute or a name attribute equal to name. The nodes in the RadioNodeList object must be sorted in tree order.
> 5. Return that **RadioNodeList** object.

I haven't found any other mention about RadioNodeList in the specs, so it seems that the only way to consistently obtain RadioNodeList is to add dummy radios, call the namedItem and remove the dummy radios, since RadioNodeList is a live collection.

```
HTMLFormElement.prototype.getRadioNodeList = function(name) {
    var result = this.elements[name];
    if(result instanceof RadioNodeList) return result;
    var dummy0;
    if(!result) {
        dummy0 = document.createElement("input");
        dummy0.type = "radio";
        dummy0.name = name;
        this.appendChild(dummy0);
    }
    var dummy1 = (dummy0||result).cloneNode();
    this.appendChild(dummy1);
    result = this.elements[name];
    dummy0?.remove();
    dummy1.remove();
    return result;
}
```

This is bad, of course, to extend objects we do not own, but at least a proposal to call in the client code

```
myform.getRadioNodeList("test").value = "a";
```

To check the radiobutton with value "a" (if any) of radiobutton group named "test" regardless of the number of items the group contains.